# Header Redirection

Tags: php, redirect, html, header

The following code doesn't work.

```
$newPageURL1 = '#post2';
$newPageURL2 = 'http://localhost/feed/all'.$newPageURL1;   

header('Location: $newPageURL2');
```

It redirects to /feed/all only without redirecting to the div position.

I need the code to redirect to /feed/all#post2

Comment: is the url ending with a slash when it is redirected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the single quotes to double quotes so php evaluates your variable

```
header("Location: $newPageURL2");
```

Comment: Or just nix the useless variables: `header("Location: http://localhost/feed/all#post2");`

Comment: Code is sometimes shortened to the problem area. you dont know how he is determining the newpageurl1